# ASP.NET MVC 5 on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos

I want to learn how to build websites using the Microsoft ASP.NET framework on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5. I will be following along with an online course that uses ASP.NET MVC 5. All of the tutorials I have read so far say to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)'s [aspnet/dnx](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) repo to install ASP.NET. However, according to the GitHub page:

> "This repository is obsolete and no longer used or maintained."

A link on the page redirects to [.Net Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos)

So, my question is: how do I install ASP.NET MVC 5 on my Mac, not .NET Core?

Thanks!

Comment: That link (to Core) *is* probably the easiest way (and with the tooling options). The _other_ way, more involved, is to install/run Windows on some VM (e.g. Parallels) and, well, you have your choices at that point since you're basically running Windows - e.g Visual Studio Code or [Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/) for tooling/IDE. Hth...

Comment: @EdSF : yeah, the VM option seems like the only route until Core is more mature. And basically this means having to run a Windows server to host the ASP.NET MVC 5 web app I'll be developing. Blah. It is what it is though.

Comment: Yup, it's actually what I do when I do dev away from home (on my mbp) - it's pretty painless and stable. The bulk of the work is in setup - but that too is pretty painless (I can only vouch for Parallels/Win 10 Pro/El Capitan) - just need to do the work...Hth..

Comment: If you do care about technical support, ASP.NET Core is the way to go like others commented. But if you just want to play with it, ASP.NET MVC 5 on Mono is possible, https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/12/jexus-web-server-and-asp-net-cross-platform/ Of course, Jexus does not work on Mac yet, but you can replace it with Apache or nginx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to start developing for .NET (including ASP.NET MVC and related technologies) on OSX, you'll need to look towards [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos). There are instructions there on how to install it and how to write code for it. There are [good examples](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started.html) linked at the bottom of the page.

Please be aware that, as of this time, the related OSX technologies are not full released, so prepare for some hiccups along the way (though...it's getting better!).

Answer (score 4):

You want to use https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

Follow the examples here once you're set up: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started.html

dnx is deprecated as mentioned on their GitHub page.

> This repository is obsolete and no longer used or maintained.

Also, for what it's worth - dnx/dnvm were CLI tooling used to build/bootstrap .net applications. They were used during the beta/rc versions of what is now known as dotnet core. The new https://github.com/dotnet/cli has replaced dnx.

Comment: Here is a specific ASP.NET Core tutorial (written March 2017): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is better than using the OS with the full capabilities as Windows to work with ASP.NET or Windows Forms (really beautiful on Windows) as a student I've been trying to get this things on mac but is kind of difficult and as future engineer, if I have to get complex operations to do something, due, something is wrong, engineering solutions is to make the easiest possible solution and that one is using Windows. Less paint in the ass.

Comment: It is totally true, if you are a engineer, get the easiest path to develop and stop wasting time forcing something that not even the creator wants to do for now, so, the best chance is to use Windows or Dual Boot, better option than using a VM (VM's will required power)