# Visual Studio 2017 for mac missing ado.net and Microsoft.Entity.Data.Model

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio-2017, ado.net

I downloaded the visual studio for mac, but I can not find the same items that I used to find in windows when I clicked on new item. The most important one for me is the ADO.net.

I googled a lot but I did not find any useful solutions.

I was hoping if anybody found a solution or even a hack in order to plug-in the ADO.net functionalities.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am not using .net Core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 5 on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799816/asp-net-mvc-5-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I checked it and it is dealing with .net core, that's why I added the update.